# Synchronizise two tables with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two tables. Both tables are editable and both tables should allways be the same :\

It wasn't my wish.. but the customer wants that :-)

So my problem is, I need to take care, that both tables have allways the same content ^^ how would you do it? Maybe with jquery and json?

Any ideas?

I use aspx, jquery, json etc pp.

Edit:

Ok here informations. Situation: The customer has a Table where he can add orders during runtime. Each order is one row in a table. The customer can edit some of the input's in the table. For one table its, no problem... but now I must have two identical tables.

So the scenario is now: Table A and Table B. The user adds, removes or changes a row in table a. Table B will recognize these changes and will synchronize the data.

The structure is:
[ IMAGE LINK ] [ Select ] [ Input ] [ Input ] [ Input ] [ Input ] [ Input ]

I am thinking about recognizing changes to the table and then clone the whole table content to the other table.

Best option would be: JSON bind to the rows :-) But I don't think its possible ;-(

Comment: And a demonstration of your mark-up?

Comment: HTML does not have editable tables. You need to give us more details e.g. how you make your tables editable etc.

Comment: Though HTML does have `tables` that can have child `td` elements with [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable).

Comment: i would show you but in the moment its a normal table with input's so nothing special

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using something along these lines:

```
$('table td').blur(
    function(){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').index(),
            col = $(this).index(),
            table = $(this).closest('table');

        $('table')
            .not(table)
            .find('tr:eq(' + row + ')')
            .find('td:eq(' + col + ')')
            .text($(this).text());
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p6pTq/).

---

**Edited** based on the comment by the OP that:

> its a normal `table` with `input`s so nothing special.

```
$('table input').blur(
    function(){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').index(),
            col = $(this).closest('td').index(),
            table = $(this).closest('table');

        $('table')
            .not(table)
            .find('tr:eq(' + row + ')')
            .find('td:eq(' + col + ') input')
            .val($(this).val());
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p6pTq/2/).

References:

- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

Hold the data in JavaScript variable and on change update both htmls. That's the general approach and all I can say without seeing your markup.